# Meaning of the structure "the...the" with no conjunctions or verbs in between?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, legalese

I encountered the following clause while reading a Shareholder Agreement:

> A Transfer Notice constitutes **the Company the** **agent** of the Seller for the sale of the Sale Shares in accordance with the provisions of this agreement.

My question: is this structure correct "the...the" without any conjunctions or verbs in between?

I had a quite similar structure as well in the same agreement:

> The Transfer Price for each **Sale Share the subject** of a Transfer Notice shall, save where expressly provided otherwise in this agreement, be the price per Sale Share (in cash) agreed between the Seller and the Board, or, in default of agreement within # Business Days of the date of service of the Transfer Notice, the Fair Value of each Sale Share determined in accordance with Clause #.

Again, two nouns without anything separating them.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not proper English.

Comment: The first example should say *constitutes the company **as** the agent...*.   The second example should say *for each Sale Share **that is** the subject of...*. At least, that's my guess.

Comment: The structure "the...the" is used in many contexts. _He gave the man the money. She likes the way the guy sings. The more the merrier_ etc. I agree with Jack O'Flaherty about your first sentence needing _as_. The word **constitute** in this context probably means _Give legal or constitutional form to (an institution); establish by law._ ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/constitute)). So it probably means, "A Transfer Notice establishes the Company by law as the agent of the Seller for the sale..." The second sentence may be as Mr O'Flaherty suggests. The English is very poor.

Comment: It looks to me like standard legal English, which is often difficult for non-lawyers to follow.